# EGL / OpenGL rendering to a surface with just a luminance channel

Tags: opengl, egl

I am (attempting) to use [EGL](https://www.khronos.org/egl) / OpenGL to perform headless rendering using a framebuffer that contains only a single luminance channel. I am able to choose a EGL configuration just fine:

```
EGLint major, minor;
eglSuccess = eglInitialize(eglDpy, &major, &minor);
assert(eglSuccess == EGL_TRUE); // success
...
static const EGLint configAttribs[] = {
    EGL_SURFACE_TYPE, EGL_PBUFFER_BIT,
    EGL_COLOR_BUFFER_TYPE, EGL_LUMINANCE_BUFFER,
    EGL_LUMINANCE_SIZE, 16,
    EGL_DEPTH_SIZE, 24,
    EGL_RENDERABLE_TYPE, EGL_OPENGL_BIT,
    EGL_NONE
};
EGLint numConfigs;
EGLConfig eglCfg;
eglSuccess = eglChooseConfig(eglDpy, configAttribs, &eglCfg, 1, &numConfigs);
assert(eglSuccess == EGL_TRUE); // success
```

But I am unable to successfully create a surface:

```
const EGLint pbufferAttribs[] = {
    EGL_WIDTH, surfaceWidth,
    EGL_HEIGHT, surfaceHeight,
    EGL_NONE,
};
eglSurf = eglCreatePbufferSurface(eglDpy, eglCfg, pbufferAttribs);
assert(eglSurf != EGL_NO_SURFACE); // fail
```

The docs for [eglCreatePbufferSurface](https://registry.khronos.org/EGL/sdk/docs/man/html/eglCreatePbufferSurface.xhtml) do not even mention a luminance option.

How do a I create a surface for rendering to a framebuffer with only luminance channel?
Does EGL even provide this option ([eglChooseConfig](https://registry.khronos.org/EGL/sdk/docs/man/html/eglChooseConfig.xhtml) seems to indicate that it is supported as the code above shows)? Am I better of trying to [render to texture](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/intermediate-tutorials/tutorial-14-render-to-texture/)?

**EDIT:**

It turns out when I query the number of configs I get `numTotalConfigs = 91`

```
eglGetConfigs(eglDpy, nullptr, 0, &numTotalConfigs);
```

None of the configs support `EGL_LUMINANCE_BUFFER`!

```
std::vector<EGLConfig> configs(numTotalConfigs);
eglGetConfigs(eglDpy, const_cast<EGLConfig*>(configs.data()),
              configs.size(), &numTotalConfigs);
for (size_t i = 0; i < configs.size(); i++) {
    const auto& config = configs[i];
    eglGetConfigAttrib(eglDpy, config, 
                       EGL_COLOR_BUFFER_TYPE, &val);
    // val == EGL_RGB_BUFFER every time!
    ...
 }
```

The device is nVidia Quadro P5000. `eglQueryDeviceStringEXT` yeilds
the following

```
 EGL_NV_device_cuda 
 EGL_EXT_device_drm 
 EGL_EXT_device_drm_render_node
 EGL_EXT_device_query_name 
 EGL_EXT_device_persistent_id
```

I guess I am out of luck on the device. Maybe try the software rendered(?)

Thanks to @Remc4 for steering me in the right direction.

Comment: What is the value of `numConfigs` after calling `eglChooseConfig()`?

Comment: @Remc4 it is zero! That is pretty limiting. Be nice to know what configs are possible.

Comment: Try reducing luminance size to 8. Or also reducing depth buffer size if that doesn't work.

Comment: @Remc4 reduced luminance size to 8, depth to 0, and a I still get 0 for `numConfigs`.  When I call `eglGetConfigs` with `nullptr` for configs I get 91 configs. I guess I will step thru those as see what I can use. BTW, using the usual RGB8 / depth24 works fine. The device is nVidia card -- I'll see what I can do.

Comment: All 91 are RGB buffers! Not a single luminance channel > 0!

Comment: Interesting. I'm not familiar with nVidia cards (I work with Android phones), but the EGL configs that are supported depend on the drivers and the hardware. You can research more on that our maybe you can encode your luminance into RGB using some arithmetic like this: https://www.shadertoy.com/view/WsVGzm

Comment: @Remc4 That scale trick is just what I need. In fact I'll add an 8-bit alpha channel to get a fill 32-bit value!